# Transfer some dataframe information to a new matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to "convert" the information of the dataframe rows **0 to 15** and columns **col1 to col 16** into an image (16x16)

I'm reading the dataframe from a .txt file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('User1/Video1.txt', sep="\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+", header=None, names=headers, engine='python', parse_dates=parse_dates)
```

```
                        date arrow  col1  col2  ...  col13  col14  col15  col16
0    2020-11-09 09:53:39.552    ->   0.0   0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1    2020-11-09 09:53:39.552    ->   0.0   2.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2    2020-11-09 09:53:39.552    ->   0.0   0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    6.0    6.0
3    2020-11-09 09:53:39.552    ->   0.0   0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
4    2020-11-09 09:53:39.586    ->   0.0   9.0  ...    0.0    7.0    0.0    0.0
...                      ...   ...   ...   ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
15   2020-11-09 09:54:06.920    ->   4.0   0.0  ...    4.0    4.0    0.0    0.0
```

After creating an empty matrix `img = np.zeros((16, 16, 3), dtype=np.uint8)` , I want to iterate over the dataframe to transfer the columns information.

For that, I thought using `df.itertuples` but I'm having problems in filling the brackets.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
     img[]][] += row[]
```

Can you provide any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) + [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)

```
#import numpy as np
np.resize(df.iloc[:16, -16:].to_numpy(), (16, 16, 3))
```

if your columns are not aligned to the right you can filter with `'col'`

```
np.resize(df.filter(regex='col').iloc[:16, :].to_numpy(), (16, 16, 3))
```